# Can you "and" jQuery selectors together?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

For example let's say you have the following:

```
<div id=1 class="a b c">...
<div id=2 class="b y c">...
<div id=3 class="b y x">...
<div id=4 class="c b">...
<div id=5 class="x 1 y">...
```

how would I select the elements that have `class="b"` AND `class="c"?`

I'm looking for a single selector that identifies div's `id=1, 2, and 4.`

Comment: Just as a note, classes beginning with a number won't work if you try to style them. For Jquery, I've never tried. I just wanna tell you.

Comment: Ohh god he asking exact my last interview Question :)   $('.b').each(function(){ $(this)hasClass('.a')  //  if condition yes -- do your process }

Comment: @Anand, check out Joe's answer. Good luck with the job hunting :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use:

```
$('.c.b')
```

as your selector, here it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/BEGZy/1/

This selects an element with both `.c` and `.b` classes.

Comment: Thank you Joe. -shakes- head I'm learning jQuery as fast as I can and it continually surprises me how easy things in it can be. I tend to look for the complex solutution when the simple ones exist.                                                                                                            To summarise: ANDing selectors: $(<selector1><selector2>...<selectorN>) ORing selectors: $(<selector1>,<selector2>,...<selectorN>)

Comment: That is: ANDing selectors: put selectors next to each other. ORing selectors: separate selectors with a commas. Simple. Thank you again.

Answer (score 3):

just like you would do with css:

```
$(".b.c").whatever()
```